# Package os and pandas conflict within a script and can't work together?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, operating-system

I have a very little script that imports the package 'os' as well as 'pandas'. As soon as pandas has been imported all 'os' commands stop working without any error message.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

os.system('ls -al &> output.txt')
```

As mentioned above this script doesn't do anything. If I remove this line of code:

```
import pandas as pd
```

then the script works fine. 
But I am confused why can't I use both packages inside one script? I am using python 3.5.2. and pandas 0.23.4. Furthermore I run the script on ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Seems very strange, are you _sure_ there isn't some other confounding factor?

Comment: You should be able to use both packages in one script. Indeed, many people do. When you say the script "doesn't do anything," does it return an error message? create the text file? etc?

Comment: It doesn't return an error message. It's like simply pressing enter in the linux terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why the problem occured but I simply restartet the server and the problem described above disappeared.